# How come my Meteor app with accounts package is not sending a verification email?

Tags: meteor, user-accounts, meteorite, email-verification

I am making a meteor app and I have the mrt accounts-password package added as well as mrt accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown.

I have added the loginbuttons so users can create an account and that works just fine. I am using all defaults.

On the server I have the code:

```
Accounts.config({
  sendVerificationEmail: true,
  forbidClientAccountCreation: false
});
```

And when I create a new account, the server console prints:

```
I20130821-18:31:42.105(-4)? ====== BEGIN MAIL #0 ======
I20130821-18:31:42.106(-4)? MIME-Version: 1.0
I20130821-18:31:42.107(-4)? From: "Meteor Accounts" <no-reply@meteor.com>
I20130821-18:31:42.108(-4)? To: hidden@hidden.edu
I20130821-18:31:42.108(-4)? Subject: How to verify email address on localhost:3000
I20130821-18:31:42.109(-4)? Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
I20130821-18:31:42.109(-4)? Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
I20130821-18:31:42.109(-4)? Hello,
I20130821-18:31:42.110(-4)? To verify your account email, simply click the link below.
I20130821-18:31:42.110(-4)? http://localhost:3000/#/verify-email/C2vJeaDLeMkkWmcRY
I20130821-18:31:42.111(-4)? Thanks.
I20130821-18:31:42.111(-4)? ====== END MAIL #0 ======
```

So it looks like it sends the email from the server but I never get the verification email in my inbox. And I tried multiple times and it has been over an hour! I also checked my spam folder. What gives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See here: http://docs.meteor.com/#email

> If MAIL_URL is not set (eg, when running your application locally), Email.send outputs the message to standard output instead

Web servers such as Meteor cannot send emails by themselves, they need a SMTP server to do that. You need to set up one and set it with `MAIL_URL` variable.

Comment: Ah I see, so do I add 'var MAIL_URL  = smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/' to the the environment file? I've never added to the env file, how do I do this?

Comment: No, you set it up as an environment variable. Alternatively, you could set it with `process.env.MAIL_URL = ...`, but this is a hacky method.

Comment: Ah so to set it up as an environment variable I just type 'export MAIL_URL = smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/' into terminal? This will add it to my local machine environment, but if I deploy to Heroku, is there a way to include a special .env file in the actual meteor project that is only readable by Heroku server?

Comment: There's a command for that: `heroku config:set MAIL_URL=...`. You'll also need to set up `ROOT_URL` and most probably `BUILDPACK_URL` the same way.

Comment: btw for others trying to get this to work, you need to add 'export MAIL_URL = smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/' replacing the smtp info with your own, into the .bash_profile, a special file on your computer that has all the environment variables. Then log out and log back in to update variables and then it should work.

Comment: Or, you can run your app with command `MAIL_URL=... meteor` - especially handy if you have several apps.

Comment: ah that is quite handy

Answer (score 14):

To configure the `MAIL_URL`, don't forget to add the core email package:

```
meteor add email
```

And then, server-side:

```
// server/smtp.js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  smtp = {
    username: 'your_username',   // eg: server@gentlenode.com
    password: 'your_password',   // eg: 3eeP1gtizk5eziohfervU
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',  // eg: mail.gandi.net
    port: 25
  }

  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
});
```

**Read More**: [Verify an Email with Meteor Accounts](http://journal.gentlenode.com/meteor-20-how-to-verify-emails-with-meteor-account/).